# Is it indeed forbidden to clean a rabies wound with alcohol?

Tags: treatment, first-aid, wound-care, rabies, rubbing-alcohol-isopropyl

I've listen to a lecture of a Russian doctor who said that "**it is forbidden to clean a rabies wound with alcholol**" ("spirt") as a first treatment, he added that it is possible to disinfect the wound with the alcohol just after a well cleaning with water and soap. He explained that the alcohol not only not help to remove the virus but it is helps it to enter...

Well, my question firstly is if it is correct or acceptable attitude in the medical world or just a personal opinion or caprice of this doctor (as sometimes it happens...)? I started to hesitate his things especially after I saw [WHO instructions](http://www.who.int/rabies/resources/SEA_CD_278_FAQs_Rabies.pdf) (p. 4) for treatment in rabbies case:

> "Wounds should be washed and flushed immediately with soap and water
>   for 10–15 minutes. If soap is not available, flush with water alone.
>   This is the most effective first-aid treatment against rabies. Wounds
>   should be cleaned thoroughly with 70% alcohol/ethanol or
>   povidone-iodine, if available".

But it is not certain because if you look at the order you'll see that first of all it's water and soap and later alcohol, but it's not necessary that the order is matter. It seems as a matter of interpretation.

Comment: The link you provided would be an excellent supporting reference for an answer saying the doctor is wrong. So you basically answered your own question: the doctor is wrong.